# Module script-scoped variables not accessable in module function's ArgumentCompleter block

Tags: powershell, module, scope, tab-completion

#### test.psm1:

```
$script:ProviderItem = [System.Management.Automation.CompletionResultType]::ProviderItem
function Get-Files {Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\en-US\about_Functions*.txt'}
function Test
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName = 'Name', Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [ArgumentCompleter({
            param ($Command, $Parameter, $WordToComplete, $CommandAst, $FakeBoundParams)
            Get-Files | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*$WordToComplete*"} | ForEach-Object {
                $resultName = $_.Name
                $resultFN = $_.FullName
                $toolTip = "File: $resultFN"
                [System.Management.Automation.CompletionResult]::new($resultName, $resultFN, $script:ProviderItem, $toolTip)
            } #ForEach-Object
        })]
        [System.String[]]$Name
    )
    begin {Write-Output $script:ProviderItem}
    process { foreach ($n in $Name) {Write-Output $n} }
}
```

### NOTES:

- This is for illustration; You could easily use `'ProviderItem'` instead of a constant in the `[System.Management.Automation.CompletionResult]` constructor.
- In this example the `Get-Files` function is intended to be a private (non-exported) function.

---

- I'm wondering why autocompletion works when `$ProviderItem` is scoped as `$global:ProviderItem` but not `$script:ProviderItem`
- In the module manifest, even if `$ProviderItem` is scoped globally I still have to export all functions, rather than just `Test`, in order to get tab-completion to work properly.

  - Doesn't Work: `FunctionsToExport = 'Test'`

    - Tab completion falls back on `TabExpansion2` and lists child items in the current directory.
  - Works: `FunctionsToExport = '*'`

    - Performs tab-completion as I expect.
- I thought this might have to do with scoping and PSReadLine, but ISE behaves the same way, so I'm obviously missing something critical.

## Questions:

- How can I use `Get-Files` inside an `ArgumentCompleter` block of a different function's parameter block(s), export only `Test` and still retain tab-completion?
- Can I avoid using the global scope for module-wide constants that are used in `ArgumentCompleter` function param blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `ArgumentCompleter` scriptblock has no knowledge about the Module it is being invoked in, thus has no knowledge about variables defined in the module scope. A simple way to prove this is the case is by changing the `CompletionResult` arguments to:

```bash
[System.Management.Automation.CompletionResult]::new(
    $resultName,
    $resultFN,
    (& (Get-Command Test).Module { $ProviderItem }),
    $toolTip)
```

Moreover, defining the variable as `$script:` is not needed, all variables defined in the `.psm1` are already scoped to the commands in your module.

Exactly the same applies for `Get-Files` if `FunctionsToExport = 'Test'`, then the it is scoped to your module and the completer scriptblock has no knowledge about it, you would've to:

```bash
& (Get-Command Test).Module { Get-Files } | Where-Object { ....
```

---

A workaround can be to use a class that implements `IArgumentCompleter` attribute, classes defined in the module scope can see the scoped variables and functions without issues, same applies to `Register-ArgumentCompleter`.

Sharing the class implementation here:

```bash
using namespace System
using namespace System.Collections
using namespace System.Collections.Generic
using namespace System.Management.Automation
using namespace System.Management.Automation.Language

$ProviderItem = [CompletionResultType]::ProviderItem

function Get-Files {
    Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\en-US\about_Functions*.txt'
}

class CustomCompleter : IArgumentCompleter {
    [IEnumerable[CompletionResult]] CompleteArgument(
        [string] $commandName,
        [string] $parameterName,
        [string] $wordToComplete,
        [CommandAst] $commandAst,
        [IDictionary] $fakeBoundParameters
    ) {
        $out = [List[CompletionResult]]::new()
        Get-Files | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "*$WordToComplete*" } | ForEach-Object {
            $resultName = $_.Name
            $resultFN = $_.FullName
            $toolTip = "File: $resultFN"
            $out.Add([CompletionResult]::new($resultName, $resultFN, $ProviderItem, $toolTip))
        }
        return $out.ToArray()
    }
}

function Test {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName = 'Name', Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [ArgumentCompleter([CustomCompleter])]
        [string[]] $Name
    )
    begin {
        Write-Output $ProviderItem
    }
    process {
        foreach ($n in $Name) {
            Write-Output $n
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I remove the global scoping, change the extension to a `.ps1` script and dot source the script it will work, so the `ArgumentCompleter` block can see `$script:` variables.  What am I missing in terms of module `$script:` vars that are visible in a function's `begin{}` block but not an `ArgumentCompleter` block vs a `.ps1` where `$script:` vars are visible in both the `ArgumentCompleter` and `begin{}` blocks?

Comment: @Paulπ the `$ExecutionContext` of the module is not the same as the `$ExecutionContext` of your session. The scriptblock of `ArgumentCompleter` can see al variables defined in your session `$ExecutionContext` but cannot see the variables defined in other modules contexts.