# Powershell Scopes with Nested Modules

Tags: powershell

What is the proper way of setting a variable in the root of a PowerShell module and making it available in its nested modules?

Setting the scope to global works but, it is now visible from other, non-nested modules.
Setting the scope to script does not work across the files, even when nested.
Setting the option to AllScope does not copy to nested modules.

I can find work-arounds but I am still hoping there is a simple, built-in solution to make a parent environment available down the tree.

If there is none, is it better to replace nested modules with dot-sourced scripts, create an external "session" module, or just use global?

Comment: Why is it important for the nested module(s) to know about the root module (in your specific case)? A nested module should generally be self-contained, only providing auxiliary commands for the root module, not care about where its loaded.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, I was trying to organize my code like you might do with partial classes in C# and hoping to get subscopes.  But, I guess this is a mistaken use for nesting modules.

Comment: Yeah I don't think splitting the code into smaller "partial" modules is the way to go, but it's hard to suggest pertinent alternatives without knowing what exactly you're trying to accomplish. Can you share more about what you're trying to do, and why you thought it'd be beneficial to split the code this way?

Comment: Systems integration.  I have an object model that data will be converted to/from.  Data flow is bidirectional so I may have dependency issues.  I'll have to rethink my design and possibly post another question.  Too much for a comment.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workarounds are similar as the ones shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78163482/15339544), you can invoke a scriptblock in the parent module context to get the variable defined in the parent module scope (`& $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Module { $var }` or `& (Get-Module Parent) { $var }`) or you can define a class in the parent module scope that holds the value of your variable in a static field:

```bash
New-Module Parent {
    $var = 'foo'
    class Test { static [string] $var = 'foo' }

    New-Module Child {
        function Get-Foo {
            & $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Module { $var }
        }

        function Get-FooFromClass {
            [Test]::var
        }
    }
} | Import-Module

Get-Foo          # foo
Get-FooFromClass # foo
```

Comment: That is interesting.  I didn't know you had a reference back to the parent module.  I don't  think I'll be able to use it in my current situation but it does answer the question and will be useful elsewhere.  Thanks.